# Help with usage: Having had?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is this proper usage? "I feel good despite not having had any coffee today."

Comment: What did you think was questionable?

Comment: The 'having had' part. Just sounded odd.

Comment: I did, thanks. Really helpful. This is my first time asking a Q on this. Do I have to close the query?

Comment: No, closing (preventing further answers) happens when enough people with sufficient reputation vote to close. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proposed construction is fine as is. “I feel good despite not having any coffee today” is indeed possible, and for the same meaning, but it might alternatively be taken as referring to the *current* lack of any beans or grounds on hand for the brewing of the beverage. Thus *had* usefully clarifies that the speaker means he or she has not drunk any of the beverage yet today.

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford English Dictionary states this on the topic:

> Another controversial issue is the insertion of have where it is superfluous, as for example I might have missed it if you hadn't have pointed it out (rather than the standard … if you hadn't pointed it out). This construction has been around since at least the 15th and 16th centuries, but only where a hypothetical situation is presented (e.g. statements starting with if). More recently, there has been speculation among grammarians and linguists that this insertion of have may represent a kind of subjunctive and is actually making a useful distinction in the language. However, it is still regarded as an error in standard English.

However, in the case you've provided here, I would err on error (ha!), since you can remove the 'had' without any consequence to the meaning of the sentence, and thus, it is superfluous.